# html links overriding virtual path

Tags: html

my application had a lot of links. 
they worked ok, until we put it on production.
(having now a relative path).

so.. all links are now broken.
i have no idea how to format them to "recognize" the new path.

`http://host/site`.

so my links are allways going to root `http://host/` instead of `http://host/site`.

HTML Code Example:

```
<div  onclick="window.location.href='/Home/Stuff/'">
    <div class="icon">
```

this link will go to `http://host/Home/Stuff/` instead of  `http://host/site/Home/Stuff`

i could hard-code but that would not be good practice.
any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? You have a link to `'/Home/Stuff'` that is currently taking you to `http://host/site` but you need it to go to `http://host/site/Home/Stuff`? Or do I have that backwards

Comment: no, it will take me to  http:/host

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://host/site">
</head>
```

`href` specifies where the paths in the HTML file should start from. This will make `/Home/Stuff/` to point to `http://host/site/Home/Stuff`.